# I want to insert, update and second time when I run Batch Class it should not add inserted records

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I want to sync all Users record with Contact. I have only one Account where I want to sync all the User records. Now I am able to insert the records with Insert call of batch apex. But I am not able to update records where User deactivates, Contact should also get deactivated. There is custom field on contact (Active checkbox).
I am not able to update records also when second time I run the batch class It do not allow me insert new records.

Please I need help!!

Here is my code...

global class ENT_Batch_sync implements Database.Batchable
{

```
String query;
Set<string> emailSet;

global ENT_Batch_sync()
{
    List<Account> lstAccountRecords = [SELECT id, Name from Account where Name = 'Standard' AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard')];
    List<Contact> lstContactRecords = [SELECT id, name, Email from Contact where AccountId =: lstAccountRecords AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard') ];
    emailSet = new Set <String>();

    for(Contact c : lstContactRecords)
    {
        emailSet.add(c.Email);
    }

    query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Title, Department, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone, IsActive from User where Email NOT IN:emailSet';
}

global ENT_Batch_sync(string userQuery)
{
    query = userQuery;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,  List<sObject> scope)
{            
    Id recordTypeId = [SELECT id, name from RecordType where Name = 'Standard' AND sObjectType = 'Contact' LIMIT 1].Id;
    List<Account> lstAccounts = [SELECT id, Name from Account where Name = 'Standard' AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard')];
    List<Contact> lstContacts = new List<Contact>();//[SELECT id, Name, Email, Title, Department, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone from Contact where AccountId =: lstAccounts AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard')];

    System.debug('***************' + scope);
    for(sobject obj : scope)
    {
        User u = (User)obj;
        if(u.IsActive == True)
        {
        Contact con = new Contact();
        for(Account acc : lstAccounts)
        {
            con.FirstName = u.FirstName ;
            con.LastName = u.LastName ;
            con.Email= u.Email; 
            con.Title = u.Title;
            con.Department = u.Department;
            con.Phone = u.Phone;
            con.MobilePhone = u.MobilePhone;
            con.AccountId = acc.id;
            con.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
            if(u.IsActive == True)
            {
                con.Active__c = True;
                System.debug('****' + con.Active__c);
            }
            else
            {
                con.Active__c = False;
                System.debug('****' + con.Active__c);
            }

            lstContacts.add(con);

            System.debug('**444** ' + lstContacts); 
        }  
        }
    }
    insert lstContacts;

    List<Account> lstAccounts1 = [SELECT id, Name from Account where Name = 'Standard' AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard')];
    List<Contact> lstContacts1 = [SELECT id, Name, Email, Title, Department, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone from Contact where AccountId =: lstAccounts AND RecordTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard')];
    for(sobject obj : scope)
    {
        User u = (User)obj;
        //Contact con = new Contact();
        for(Account acc : lstAccounts1)
        {
          for(Contact con : lstContacts1 ) 
          {
            if(con.Email == u.Email)
            {
                con.FirstName = u.FirstName ;
                con.LastName = u.LastName ;
                con.Email= u.Email; 
                con.Title = u.Title;
                con.Department = u.Department;
                con.Phone = u.Phone;
                con.MobilePhone = u.MobilePhone;
                con.AccountId = acc.id;
                con.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
                if(u.IsActive == True)
                {
                    con.Active__c = True;
                    System.debug('****' + con.Active__c);
                }
                else
                {
                    con.Active__c = False;
                    System.debug('****' + con.Active__c);
                }

                lstContacts1.add(con);
                System.debug('**444** ' + lstContacts); 
             }
           }
        }

    }
    update lstContacts1;

}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}
```

}

Comment: In what way are you not allowed to update records on the second run? Can you narrow it down by providing the error details and the applicable lines in the example you provided.